Пытаюсь сделать поиск по названию папки в директории
Я пытаюсь реализовать поиск папок по названию в директории, но на данный момент мой код позволяет искать только файлы, либо по названию, либо по расширению, например.exe.
Мне необходима помощь в написании кода, который бы позволял осуществлять поиск именно папок по их названию.
import os
     
for root, dirs, folders in os.walk('C://Users/Nmm Code/AppData'):
    for folder in folders:
        if folder.endswith('Exloader'):
            print(os.path.join(root, folder))


dirs, folders ← ничего вот здесь не смущает?

Ну поиск в директориях идёт

Можешь скинуть код как вообще это реализовать, а то читая документацию os и смотря на форумах я нашел только поиск .txt , .exe и т.д. файлов. А именно поиск папок не могу найти.

То есть вы в документации так до сих пор и не увидели, что такое dirs?

Нет не увидел, можете показать простой пример на подобии этого кода, как сделать поиск папок по названию папки, а то я сделал по всем этим, только поиск файлов.
